# How to convert a json to an xml thats readable by the datatable.xmlread() class in c#

Tags: c#, python, json, xml

I have a file that is read by a program written in c# (example below). I'm trying to figure out how to take a json that I create in python and turn it into an xml with identical formatting to the one above, except with different values (and a different number of ?children?), so that it can be read into this other program. I know the program uses the datatable.xmlread() class to bring this xml in. Is there any reasonable way to do this using python 3.5 or later (no lxml currently...)? alternatively, is there a way to do this with c#? I know nearly nothing about c# (I would barely say i know anything about python or coding in general for that mater...) so some direction to a good resource would be awesome.

The xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
  <List>
    <Name>TC Body</Name>
    <ID>33281</ID>
    <Output>75.4</Output>
    <System>2</System>
  </List>
  <List>
    <Name>PT Inlet</Name>
    <ID>40730</ID>
    <Output>12.5</Output>
    <System>2</System>
  </List>
  <List>
    <Name>SG Frame</Name>
    <ID>28780</ID>
    <Output>999.99</Output>
    <System>1</System>
  </List>
</DocumentElement>
```

I have no problem getting the json into an xml, just can't get it to be in a format that the c# program will take...

Comment: You cant find some good coding tutorials at [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/)

Comment: What does the JSON look like that you want to transform into XML?

Comment: I'm building it so I can make it look however I want... ATM it's​ set up the same as the XML above except the ID is the dictionary key...

Answer (score 0):

Do either of these suit your needs?

- [json2xml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/json2xml)
- [dicttoxml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dicttoxml)

Personally I'd try the latter one. The first operates on files, so you'd have to output the file, read it back in, and make the other output. Sounds messy and inefficient. The latter works on strings so you can pass your JSON string into it and receive an XML string, then output both at the same time. (Recall: JSON are valid dicts so it should work for JSON as well as arbitrary dicts.)

Comment: So my problem really isn't getting the json into an xml, it's getting it in the right format to be read into a c# program using the datatable.readxml() class... Python has several built in libraries to build an XML from a dictionary...